# Copy whole directory from source to destination using immediate parent folder as reference in both location

Tags: shell-script

**

- Problem 1:

**
Pre-requiste: Both source and destionion should have the same directory name. Directory's depth level may vary both not the name

Notes on source and destination structure:

1. sampleFolder and Project1 is the only common part in paths
2. There are multiple directories that need to copied
3. Directories and not in same path they may be one level deep, two level deep , so basically I need to search for reference folder before coping file

```
mydir
|__ sampleFolder/fil.txt
|__ Project1/fil2.txt

desDir
  |__ some_path/More_path/sampleFolder/
  |__ some_path/More_path/some_more_path/Project1/
```

Aim: Copy files in folder `mydir/sampleFolder/file.txt` to `desDir/some_path/sampleFolder/file.txt`

Note: path hierarchy is different but `sampleFolder` is same in both source and destination path

Command

```
find $HOME/mydir/ -type f -name *.txt -exec sh -c 'cp {}' 'find $HOME/des_dir -type d -path `echo $(dirname -- {}) | sed s"~$HOME/mydir~~g"`' sh {} \;
```

Command breakup 1: This will get parent directory and remove `$HOME/mydir` from searched `*.txt` file path

```
echo $(dirname -- {}) | sed s"~$HOME/mydir~~g"
```

Command breakup 2: this will search for path matching string received after executing command breakup 1

```
find $HOME/des_dir -type d -path
```

Command breakup 3: This is common (i guess)

```
find $HOME/mydir/ -type f -name *.txt -exec sh -c 'cp {}'
```

**

- Problem 2

**
Problem1 got resolved using below command & it works fine if I run it in cygwin as stand alone command

```
find $HOME/MY_DIR/ -type d -name data -exec sh -c 'rsync -avz {} `find $HOME/DES_DIR-type d -name $(basename $(dirname -- {}))`' sh {} \;
```

but if I use this command in shell script and run script in cygwin it gives error

```
protocol version mismatch - is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)

rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(60)
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking ?

Comment: Do I understand correct that you want to copy all files from `sampleFolder` somewhere in `mydir` to a `sampleFolder` somewhere (maybe somewhere else) in `desDir`?  I suggest to should show an example of what files and directory structure you have as source and target and what result you want to get. There should be more than one file and if applicable more than one subdirectory like `sampleFolder` in the example. What if there are two or more `sampleFolder` below `desDir`, e.g. `desDir/some_path/sampleFolder` and `desDir/foo/bar/sampleFolder`? What if `sampleFolder` does not exist in `desDir`?

Comment: @Bodo your understanding exactly correct ...

Comment: You didn't clearly answer the questions what should happen if a directory in  `mydir` is not found in `desDir` or if there are more matching directories in `desDir`. The text "Note2: There are multiple such paths" is not clear to me. Are all files to be copied in direct subdirectories of `mydir` or could there also be `mydir/foo/bar/baz/file.xyz`? Do all file names match `*.txt` or can there be any file name?

Comment: @Bodo **a)** Their will always be a matching directory in `desDir`, to be on safer side we can makedir if it is not present  **b)** Yes all files, sub-directory  needs to be copied ...*.txt was a example

Comment: @RaviYadav Please use the [edit] link to add this information **to the question**. According to your question only the name of the leaf directory is relevant, the parent directory in `desDir` is variable, so it is unclear where to `mkdir` if a matching directory is not found. You didn't answer the question what should happen if there is more than one matching directory in `desDir`. Since you want to copy all subdirectories, the requirements are not fully clear. For example what if there is `mydir/sampleFolder/Project1/fil3.txt`?

Comment: @Bodo it will not have more than matching directory , all files/folder under `mydir/sampleFolder` should be copied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit ambiguous what you're trying to do, but `rsync` may be suitable if you're planning to copy whole directories.

e.g.

```
$ rsync -avz level2 level3/test/
sending incremental file list
level2/
level2/out.txt
level2/rds.aws.test.lambda.json

sent 380 bytes  received 58 bytes  876.00 bytes/sec
total size is 341  speedup is 0.78
$ ls level3/test/
level2
$ ls level3/test/level2/
out.txt  rds.aws.test.lambda.json
```

If you wanted only the *.txt files and preserving the directory structure, you need to add the `R` option to rsync

```
$  rsync -avzR level2/*.txt level3/test2
sending incremental file list
level2/
level2/out.txt

sent 178 bytes  received 39 bytes  434.00 bytes/sec
total size is 65  speedup is 0.30

$ ls level3/test2/level2/
out.txt
```

Comment: I suggest to modify your answer to match the sample structure from the question. Otherwise it is difficult to understand how/if your answer fits the OP's use case.

Comment: @Mylo  I wanted to do rsync -avz level2 level3/test/..thanks a lot

Comment: @Mylo before doing rsync i need to search parent directory of *.txt so that I can transfer all the files in that folder

Comment: Below worked for me @Mylo thanks  **find Mydir/ -type d -name data -exec sh -c 'rsync -avz {} `find desDir  -type d -name $(basename $(dirname -- {}))`' sh {} \;**